# No line numbers in VS 2010 despite checked

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem with visual studio not displaying line numbers despite having checked "Line numbers" in Tools -> Options. I have included a pic with proof, and all the solutions I have found don't answer this. How can I enable line number, despite already having enabled it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K3dv.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have it enabled for all languages - the square means that it's enabled for *some* languages, but obviously not the one you care about.

Just click the check box twice - the first will remove it for all languages, the second will select it for all languages.

Answer (score 0):

The blue box in the checkbox for line numbering in the `All Languages` group means that line numbering is language-dependent.

Either put a tick there (to enable line numbering for all languages), or in the C/C++ - specific line numbering option (to enable line numbering for C/C++).